# Class with multiple functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, module, ecmascript-6, prototype

I try to make a function that can either show a confirmation window or a dialog form. Both these two functions are in the same window, so I might reuse the code in both.

I guess it should be something like

```
const MyWindow = function (options) {
};

MyWindow.prompt = function (options) {
  ..
};

MyWindow.confirm = function (options) {
  ...
}

MyWindow.alert = function (options) {
  ...
}
```

The problem is that I don't know where to draw the window.

I have tried creating a new method

```
const MyWindow = function (options) {
};

MyWindow.createElements = function (options) {
  this.window = document.createElement('div');
  this.window.style.height = 300;
  this.window.style.width = 300;
  document.body.insertBefore(this.window, document.body.childNodes[0]);
};

MyWindow.prompt = function (options) {
  this.createElements();
  this.window.style.background-color = 'red';
};
```

but `this.createElements()` and `this.window` are not accessible from the `prompt()` function.

How do you normally develop something like this? Should I use ES6 classes?

Comment: You're using `MyWindow` function like it was an object (this is possible, though). Make it an objet instead of function.

Comment: Is `MyWindow` supposed to be a singleton module or a constructor for instances?

Comment: Yes, you should use ES6 classes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.prototype` to extend a class. This should help you...

Refer [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)

```js
var MyWindow = function (options) {
}

MyWindow.prototype.createElements = function (options) {
  this.window = document.createElement('div');
  this.window.style.height = '300px';
  this.window.style.width = '300px';
  document.body.insertBefore(this.window, document.body.childNodes[0]);
};

MyWindow.prototype.prompt = function (options) {
  this.createElements();
  this.window.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}

var el = new MyWindow()
el.prompt()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use functions and the new-keyword. This will create a new object with access to alert and prompt, while the init-method is private for MyWindow.

```js
const MyWindow = function() {
  const init = () => console.log("do init stuff");

  this.alert = () => {
    init();
    console.log("alert!");
  };

  this.prompt = () => {
    init();
    console.log("prompt");
  }
}

const myWindow = new MyWindow();

myWindow.alert();
myWindow.prompt();
```

Answer (score 0):

when you say class you could have a look at ES2015 which is the *new* Javascript. Let me give you an example:

`class Person {
    constructor(name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    sayHello() {
        console.log('Hello ' + this.name + ' wow you are ' + this.age + ' years old');
    }
}`

I would use ES2015 **[literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)** in the example above in my console log but I can't do this on here, or can I?

To use the class above you would just do:

`const person = new Person('Jack', 21)`

`person.sayHello()`

*output - Hello Jack wow you are 21 years old*

So that's an example of you would would write a class in ES2015 with some methods. If you want to add methods to a 'class' the older way you would just do something like:

`function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}`

To add a method (extend) your function you just need to use prototype like so:

`Person.prototype.sayHello = function() {
    console.log('Hello ' + this.name + ' wow you are ' + this.age + ' years old');
}`